# Email no llega al ser enviado con PHP

Tags: php, email, hosting

Estoy desarrollando en PHP un sistema que envía email a la dirección que el usuario proporciona.

El programa devuelve true cuando utilizo la función `mail()`, hice pruebas enviando correos al dominio gmail es decir `micorreo@gmail.com` pero cuando intento enviar correos a otro dominio los correos no llegan, el correo se envía cómo mencioné anteriormente pero el correo nunca llega.

¿De donde puede venir el problema? de mi servidor está alojado en 000webhost versión gratuita, anteriormente estaba en awardspace versión gratuita también pero en este ultimo directamente los correos no se enviaban

Comment: Puede que necesites revisar los DNS ya que algunos servidores como google o hotmail requieren que agregues algunos TXT a tu dominio Saludos :)

Comment: Requieren los TXT para aceptar correos de mi servidor/dominio?

Comment: Por si acaso, te recuerdo que el valor que devuelve mail (true/false) significa que se ha aceptado para enviar, pero no que haya llegado al destino. Revisa la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, leí esa misma página antes de publicar mi pregunta

Comment: Pues en mi caso si fue así, yo envió correos a gmail y hotmail diariamente y al principio funcionaba perfecto hasta que se llego a un limite de mensajes, al contactar a soporte de google me comentan que esto era para evitar spam así que debía verificar mi servidor agregando algo como esto a mis dns

v=spf1 ip4:IP_SERVIDOR -all

Ahora funciona sin problemas :)

Comment: Entonces sugieres que contacte con el proveedor del dominio que no acepta mis emails?